# Proper way to get a specific item by it's property from Doctrine's collections

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working with doctrine for the first time in my own project. I'm facing a problem with finding the right object from a collection returned from a doctrine one-to-many relation.

Let's say I have an entity `Page` which has a lot of `Section` sub-entities.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Pages")
 */
class Page 
{
    // bunch of properties

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Section", mappedBy="page")
     * @var Collection 
     */ 
    protected $sections;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->sections = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getSections(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sections;
    }

}
```

Now what I want to achieve is to be able to get the `Section` by it's name (I should probably mention that the `name` is a property of the `Section` entity).

So at the end I want to be able to achieve something similar to:

```
class SomeController 
{

    public function HomePageAction() 
    {
        $page = $this->getEntityManager()
                     ->getRepository('App:Entity:Page')
                     ->findOneBy(array('name' => 'homepage'));

        $section = $page->findSectionByName('header');

        // rendering etc.
    }

}
```

I can, of course, loop through all of the sections and return one that matches the name I'm looking for (throw the exception if none) or I'm wondering if there isn't some easier way to do that? Also, is it something I should do in some sort of custom repository class, or is it ok to leave the method `findSectionByName` inside the `Entity` class? Thank you in advance.

So, what I tried so far...

```
// class App\Entity\Page
public function getSectionByName(string $name)
{
    foreach ($this->getSections() as $section) {
        if ($section->getName() === $name) 
            return $section;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to use the **matching(Criteria $criteria)** function on your collection.

So:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

public function getSectionByName(string $name)
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('name', $name))
        ->setFirstResult(0)
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    return $this->getSections()->matching($criteria)->first();
}
```

If you want to throw a not found exception, the best practice would be to do it in your action:

```
public function HomePageAction() 
{
    $page = $this->getEntityManager()
                 ->getRepository('App:Entity:Page')
                 ->findOneBy(array('name' => 'homepage'));

    $section = $page->findSectionByName('header');

    if($section === false) {
        //here throw your exception.
    }
    // rendering etc.
}
```

More about filtering doctrine's collections can be found in [Doctrine - Working with Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

Comment: Great! I didn't even know about the `Criteria` doctrine provides. Actually, you can consider adding a documentation for the criteria to your answer as it will be more useful for other users. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate custom repository in your `Page` entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
{
    ....
}
```

after that in your `App\Repository\PageRepository` define function that will be get sections by page and section name

```
    // App\Repository\PageRepository
    public function getSectionByPageAndName($pageName, $sectionName)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('s')
            ->from(Page::class, 'p')
            ->join(Section::class, 's')
            ->where('p.name = :pageName')
            ->andWhere('s.name = :sectionName')
            ->setParameter('pageName', $pageName)
            ->setParameter('sectionName', $sectionName)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

After that you can you this function easy 
over and over again, just in your controllers call function on repository

```
class SomeController
{

    public function HomePageAction()
    {
        $sections = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('App:Entity:Page')
            ->getSectionByPageAndName($pageName, $sectionName);

        //etc
    }

}
```

cause you relationship is `@OneToMany` and if `sectionName` is not unique `$sections` will be empty array or array of `Section` objects, If you want to limit to only one result or something else please check [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I understand the approach here, but I do need to find the section inside my existing Page entity (As I will use every section and the page entity itself). Your solution provides me a great way to fetch the section, but the thing in my case, is to actually get the Page, work with it and then easily navigate through it's sections (verbosely - that's why I choose to find it by name) so I can extract more information about the page exactly where I need it. Otherwise, thanks for help and for trying. +1